# Is this hadith about the virtue of Ayat al-Kursy authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, wudu

> whomsoever recites ayat kursi after wudhu Allah will count it as if he has done 40 years of ibadah and will raise him 40 ranks and will marry him off with 40 hurun ain

From Ad-Dailami by Ibn Umar

Is this hadith authentic? Are there any other chain of narrators .

Answer (score 2):

This hadith is fabricated and false as stated in the fatwa islamqa #[192341](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/192341/a-false-and-fabricated-hadith-about-the-virtue-of-reciting-aayat-al-kursiy-immediately-after-doing-wudoo)

> This hadith is false and fabricated. This report was narrated by ad-Daylami in Musnad al-Firdaws, and a similar report was narrated in Kanz al-‘Ummaal (9/465), via Muqaatil ibn Sulaymaan: Fadl ibn ‘Ubayd told us, from Sufyaan ath-Thawri, from ‘Ubaydullah al-‘Umari, from Naafi‘, from Ibn ‘Umar, and attributed to the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him): “Whoever recites Aayat al-Kursiy after doing wudoo’, Allah will give him the reward of forty scholars, and raise him forty degrees in status, and give him in marriage forty of al-hoor al-‘iyn.” This is a fabricated isnaad. **Muqaatil ibn Sulaymaan** was a well-known liar. An-Nasaa’i said: The liars who were well known for fabricating hadith were: Ibn Abi Yahya in Madinah, al-Waaqidi in Baghdad, Muqaatil ibn Sulaymaan in Khurasaan, and Muhammad ibn Sa‘eed in Syria.
>
> End quote from Mizaan al-I‘tidaal (3.562) (Qute from the [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/192341/a-false-and-fabricated-hadith-about-the-virtue-of-reciting-aayat-al-kursiy-immediately-after-doing-wudoo) above)

Elsewhere I found a statement of imam a-Shawkani commenting the narration: it includes Muqaatil ibn Sulaymaan who is a liar (Source in Arabic islamweb #[76015](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/76015/))

The strongest ahadith on the virtues of recitation of ayat al-Kursi are those recommending its recitation after each ordered prayer:

> it was narrated that Abu Umaamah said: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever recites Aayat al-Kursiy immediately after each prescribed prayer, there will be nothing standing between him and his entering Paradise except death.” This is how it was narrated by al-Nasaa’i in al-Yawm wa’l-Laylah, from al-Hasan ibn Bishr. It was also narrated by Ibn Hibbaan in his Saheeh from Muhammad ibn Humayr, who is al-Homsi, and is also one of the men of al-Bukhaari. The isnaad meets the conditions of al-Bukhaari.  (See for example in fatwa islamqa #[6092](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/6092/aayat-al-kursiy))

Furthermore you may find other recommendations for reciting it in Tafsir ibn Kathir see for example [on qtafsir](http://m.qtafsir.com/Surah-Al-Baqara/The-Virtue-of-Ayat-Al-Kursi).

Comment: Jazakallahukhairan